# What is the "Performing multiple tasks" button do in Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I recently stumbled a button in Powerpoint 2010 that has the following tooltip text:

> Performing multiple tasks. Click to show next task.

The button is in the lower right on the statusbar (next to the view options and zoom slider) and looks like three horizontal, partially green bars (will upload a screenshot later).
Clicking the button does nothing visible.

What is the function of the button?

Comment: Is it part of an Add In? I have PowerPoint 2010 and do not see what you describe.

Comment: Hmm, very well possible. It's on a corporate laptop, so I'm not sure what plugins are installed/enabled. Will check and update the question. Also I'll try to upload a screenshot, but for some reason this didn't work. To the close voter: care to explain how this is primarily opinion based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is related to SharePoint sync, for example when you open/save a doc from sharepoint/WebDAV it's sometimes done in the background/not blocking Powerpoint. The status will be shown there and clicking the button will show a list of outstanding tasks.